# Counting in Many to Many Relations in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, counting

I have a table A and B, and their many to many relations in table AB.

```
Select A.id, AB.bId FROM A LEFT JOIN AB on A.id = AB.aId
```

gives

```
A1--B1
A1--B2
A2--B3
A3--NULL
A4--B4
```

I want to find total number of distict A's and total number of distinct A's having a not null B. e.g. for above table, the numbers and 4 and 3. In fact, I am wondering the percentage 3/4=0.75.

Can I do this in one optimal query?

Comment: Andomar's answer is correct and fine, but just for fun, try counting different things like COUNT(a.id),COUNT(ab.bid) FROM .... GROUP BY a.id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `count()` does not count `null`, you could:

```
select  count(distinct A.id) as DistinctA
,       count(distinct case 
                       when AB.bId is not null then A.id
                       end) as DistinctAHavingNotNullB
from    A 
left join
        AB 
on      A.id = AB.aId
```

Note that a `case` without `else` returns `null` when no `when` clause matches.